# how to implement asynchronous job scheduler in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

now  am trying to write a job scheduler ,when each request came it will start a  thread for job . is it possible to change job asynchronous  tasks in Java script.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What exactly is a "scheduler". My assumption is that it is a piece of software that will execute other pieces of software at a specified time. Basically cron. But my assumption may be wrong. Since I can't be sure if my understanding of your question is as per you intended your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can use an implementation of a promises framework. This frameworks help with synchronizing different asynchronous jobs. A promise is something that can succeed or fail but either way it will terminate one way or the other.

AngularJs has an [implementation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) of a promise framework. If you don't need angular you can use a different promise framework like this one: [promisejs](https://www.promisejs.org/)